# Why is this LUT convolution implementation slower than non-LUT one

Tags: performance, matlab, lookup, convolution

I've implemented a convolution algorithm with Look-Up Table and one without it for my Computer Vision course.
I used *tic; command; toc;* to measure the algorithm's performance.
I expected the LUT implementation to be faster than the non-LUT one, but that's not what is happening in my case and I can't understand why.
Sometimes I solve this kind of problems by avoiding implicit casts (converting everything to double before computation starts). I've also tried using smaller types, like single, but it seems to slow down the process.
What am I doing wrong?
The non-LUT implementation is always 0.2 seconds slower, and this difference increases with the kernel dimensions.
I use a grayscale image as input, and fspecial() to create the kernel.
I post the code of both the implementations.
**LUT:**

```
function out = convolutionLUT(img, k)
[h, w] = size(img);
[kh, kw] = size(k);
floorkh = floor(kh/2);
floorkw = floor(kw/2);
img = double(img);
out = zeros(h, w);
lut = zeros(kh, kw, 256);
for i=1:256
    lut(:,:,i) = k * (i-1);
end
for x=1:w-kw+1
    for y=1:h-kh+1
        prd = 0;
        for i=1:kw
            for j=1:kh
                prd = prd + lut(j, i, img(y+j-1, x+i-1)+1);
            end
        end
        out(y+floorkh, x+floorkw) = prd;
    end
end
out = uint8(255 * out/max(out(:)));
end
```

**non-LUT:**

```
function out = convolution(img, k)
[h, w] = size(img);
[kh, kw] = size(k);
floorkh = floor(kh/2);
floorkw = floor(kw/2);
img = double(img);
out = zeros(h, w);
for x=1:w-kw+1
    for y=1:h-kh+1
        prd = 0;
        for i=1:kw
            for j=1:kh
                prd = prd + k(j,i) * img(y+j-1, x+i-1);
            end
        end
        out(y+floorkh, x+floorkw) = prd;
    end
end
out = uint8(255 * out/(max(out(:))));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

With your non-LUT code it's easily predictable what data the code accesses. Probably the Matlab JIT-Compiler found a way to use this knowledge to improve the performance.

Besides this LUT/non-LUT difference it seems you are wasting performance. Take a look at this pice of code:

```
prd = 0;
for i=1:kw
    for j=1:kh
       prd = prd + k(j,i) * img(y+j-1, x+i-1);
    end
end
```

You could replace it with a single vectorized multiplication:

```
prd=sum(sum(k(1:kh,1:kw).*img(y:y+kh-1, x:x+kw-1)))
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your attention. Trying your code (replacing those inner for with your single line) results in an improvement when the kernel is at least 17x17 big. Otherwise, my implementation results faster. Have you tested it? Do you obtain the same performances?

Comment: On my PC the vectorised version runs faster for any kernel sizes. What matlab version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MATLAB R2014a 8.3.0.532 64-bit. I'm surprised of these results today, because some time ago the LUT version always appeared faster compared to the other solution. Is there any way to manage those JIT-compiler optimizations? Just to be sure that it's due to strange abstractions or if I'm really doing something wrong.
Anyway, using _feature accel off_ really shows the improvement from my code to yours. Does MATLAB use a private JRE or does it use the one I install on my system? Because that's the only thing I've changed in my system during these months.

Comment: I assume my code and the LUT-Version did not change in performance but the non-LUT version became faster in Matlab 14a. Maybe someone who has access to different versions can benchmark the code